# Return softDeleted relation rows

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I have a table, called "bsService", where I save my created services. Those services have some relations, like categories, activities and others.

I'm trying to get services where categories was softDeleted. Example: service 1 relates to category 1, I softDeleted category 1, and now this service doesn’t return on `findAll` even if add 'withDeleted: true' on the query.

Here's my `findAll` method. I want all data even if a relation is softDeleted.

```javascript
findAll = async (
    where?: WhereConditions,
    transactionEntityManager: EntityManager = getManager(),
    order?: 'ASC' | 'DESC',
    withDeleted?: boolean,
  ): Promise<BSService[]> => transactionEntityManager.find(BSService, {
    withDeleted,
    where,
    relations: ['sla', 'activity', 'activity.category', 'department', 'department.company', 'attendance', 'logs', 'logs.user', 'requestingAgent', 'alocatedAgent', 'category', 'requestingAgent.jobs', 'alocatedAgent.jobs'],
    order: {
      updateAt: order,
    },
  });
```

The 'withDeleted' becomes true, depending on which page client is using. For that example, it is always true.

Comment: Can you confirm that the service is still present in the database?

Comment: @DemiPixel yes sir, all the records still on DB.

Comment: As silly as this might seem, could you hardcode `withDeleted,` instead with `withDeleted: true`? Also, what are your `where` conditions? Perhaps that's excluding the deleted rows?

Comment: @DemiPixel i checked twice my where, is just selecting step of the service, nothing that could exclude the softDeleted ones. That part of hardcode withDeleted seems kinda confusing, could you explain me more?

Comment: Try setting in your settings `maxQueryExecutionTime` to 1 (this will effectively print every query). Then you can see the actual query it's making and debug from there (is it the wrong query or is the query not returning the expected result in psql?) https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/logging.md#log-long-running-queries

Comment: @demiPixel sorry for the delay to answer, i was out thoses days. So i enabled the loggs and see the query, the thing is, for every relation on the query, the deleteAt are beign sended like this AND (`BSService__category`.`deleteAt` IS NULL), onlye the main table ('bsservice') are finding the softDeleted. That's the point, how do i insert withDeleted on the relations to, not only on the 'bsservice'.

Comment: Is "softDeleted" literal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withDeleted` in `.find()` only applies to the top layer, not relations.

[Here's someone with a similar issue.](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7490)

[Here's a PR](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/7296) that shows how you can solve it by using a query builder with `.withDeleted()` before the relations you want to include. There's some discussion about supporting this with `.find()` but it seems like it won't be any time soon.

```tsx
await manager
  .getRepository(BSService)
  .createQueryBuilder('bsservice')
  .withDeleted() // Above innerJoinAndSelects
  .innerJoinAndSelect('bsservice.sla', 'sla')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('bsservice.activity', 'activity')
  // ... more inner joins ...
  .getMany();
```

Comment: Thank you, @DemiPixel, this could work! One last thing, in some relations there are a relation inside a relation, example: activity.category, category it's a relation inside the activity and, activity it's a relation inside bsservice, so, when i try to use .innerJoinAndSelect('bsservice.activity.category', 'activity') doenst work, i tried change activity to category, didn't worked too.

Comment: Forget it, i found the answer. Again, thank you so much for the help!